# How to properly print special key sequences with terminfo in terminal-agnostic way?

Tags: c, curses, terminfo

I am trying to emulate a user, pressing such special keys as `<Left Arrow>`, `<Backspace>`, `<Delete>` and so on. I heard that curses/terminfo might help to do that in terminal-agnostic way, but when i try (with following code) to print first string "text" and then emmit a `key_left` sequence, i am not getting a (with `'|'` as cursor) `"tex|t"`, but rather `"textD|"`. Why? How to do that properly?

```
#include <term.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void putf(const char *name) {
  putp(name);
  fflush(stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  setupterm((char*)0, 1, (int*)0);

  printf("text");
  fflush(stdout);

  putf(key_left);

  // hang up until user input
  fgetc(stdin);

  return 0;
}
```

Please note, while i am okay with using curses, ncurses is unacceptable in my use-case.
Also, note that i don't want to use something like `initscr()`, replacing current terminal screen with blank one, it is not a desired behavior.

Comment: Key sequences are not cursor movement commands. You should not output them at all, only detect them in the input.

Comment: I am implementing sort of own readline and i need to somehow render editing commands to escape sequences accordingly to current terminal type and settings.

Comment: If you want to move the cursor to the left, use `cursor_left`, not `key_left`. See `man terminfo` for more commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape sequences responsible for cursor movement, and escape sequences associated with arrow keys, are generally distinct and should not be used instead of each other. In the `terminfo` database, the former are prefixed with `cursor` and the latter with `key`.

Thus, to move the cursor to the left, one should use `putp (cursor_left)`, not `putp (key_left)`.